# Optimized 53->32 bit modulo computation on 32-bit processors

Tags: c, algorithm, micro-optimization, integer-division

This question arose when I looked into the efficient implementation of the MRG32k3a PRNG on 32-bit processors without, or slow, support for `double` computation. I am particularly interested in ARM, RISC-V, and GPUs. MRG32k3a is a very high-quality PRNG and therefore still in wide-spread use today although it dates to the late 1990s:

P. L'Ecuyer, "Good parameters and implementations for combined multiple recursive random number generators." *Operations Research*, Vol. 47, No. 1, Jan.-Feb. 1999, pp. 159-164

MRG32k3a combines two recursive sequences of the form *(c<sub>0</sub> ⋅ state<sub>0</sub> - c<sub>1</sub> ⋅ state<sub>1</sub>) mod m*, where *state<sub>i</sub> < m*. The constants and state variables in MRG32k3a are all positive integers that fit into 32 bits, and all intermediate expressions in the computation are less than 2<sup>53</sup> in magnitude. This is by design, as the reference implementation uses IEEE-754 `double` for storage and computation. The mathematical modulus *mod* differs from ISO-C's `%` operator by always delivering a non-negative result. The first variant in the code below shows the slightly modernized reference implementation using `double`.

In integer-only implementation of MRG32k3a 32-bit variables are used for state components, and intermediate computations are performed in 64-bit arithmetic. The modulo is easily computed via `%` by ensuring that the dividend is non-negative: *(c<sub>0</sub> ⋅ state<sub>0</sub> - c<sub>1</sub> ⋅ state<sub>1</sub>) mod m = (c<sub>0</sub> ⋅ state<sub>0</sub> - c<sub>1</sub> ⋅ state<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>1</sub> ⋅ m) % m.* The computation `% m` is expensive on 32-bit processors, usually resulting in a library call. This is easily addressed via standard division-by-constant optimizations, with a 64-bit multiply-high computation as the most expensive part (see the `GENERIC_MOD=1` variant in the code below).

Even faster modulo computation is possible when the magnitude of the dividend is restricted and *m = 2<sup>n</sup>-d*, with small *d*. One sets *lo = x % 2<sup>n</sup>, hi= x / 2^<sup>n</sup>, t = hi * d + lo*. As long as *t < 2 ⋅ m*, *x mod m = (t >= m) ? (t - m) : t*. The desired condition holds when *x < 2<sup>n+(n-ceil(log2(d+1)))</sup>*. This works well for the first recurrence used by MRG32k3a, with *n=32* and *d=209* which requires *x < 2<sup>56</sup>*, which is trivially satisfied. But for the second recurrence *n=32* and *d = 22853*, requiring *x < 2<sup>49</sup>*. After applying the offset *c<sub>1</sub> ⋅ m* to ensure a positive *x*, *x* can be as large as *8.15 ⋅ 10<sup>15</sup>* in this case, only very slightly less than *2<sup>53</sup> ≈ 9 ⋅ 10<sup>15</sup>*.

I am currently addressing this by basing the offset added to ensure positive `x` prior to computing `x % m` on the value of the state variables, and this keeps *x < 2<sup>44</sup>*. But as one can see from the relevant code lines extracted below, this is a fairly expensive approach which includes a 32-bit division (with constant divisor and thus optimizable, but still incurring undesirable cost).

```c
    prod = ((uint64_t)a21) * MRG32k3a_s22i - ((uint64_t)a23n) * MRG32k3a_s20i;
    adj = MRG32k3a_s20i / 3133 - (MRG32k3a_s22i >> 13) + 1;
    prod = ((int64_t)(int32_t)adj) * (int64_t)m2 + prod; // ensure it's positive
```

Are there alternative and less costly mitigation strategies that lead to a more efficient modulo computation for the second recurrence used by MRG32k3a?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#define BUILTIN_64BIT (0)
#define GENERIC_MOD   (0)  // applies ony when BUILTIN_64BIT == 0

static double MRG32k3a_s10, MRG32k3a_s11, MRG32k3a_s12;
static double MRG32k3a_s20, MRG32k3a_s21, MRG32k3a_s22;

/* SIMD vectorized by Clang with -ffp-model=precise on x86-84 and AArch64
   SIMD vectorized by Intel compiler with -fp-model=precise -march=core-avx2
 */
double MRG32k3a (void)
{
    const double norm = 2.328306549295728e-10;
    const double m1 = 4294967087.0;
    const double m2 = 4294944443.0;
    const double a12 = 1403580.0;
    const double a13n = 810728.0;
    const double a21 = 527612.0;
    const double a23n = 1370589.0;
    double k, p1, p2;

    /* Component 1 */
    p1 = a12 * MRG32k3a_s11 - a13n * MRG32k3a_s10;
    k = floor (p1 / m1);  
    p1 -= k * m1;
    MRG32k3a_s10 = MRG32k3a_s11; MRG32k3a_s11 = MRG32k3a_s12; MRG32k3a_s12 = p1;
    /* Component 2 */
    p2 = a21 * MRG32k3a_s22 - a23n * MRG32k3a_s20;
    k = floor (p2 / m2);  
    p2 -= k * m2;
    MRG32k3a_s20 = MRG32k3a_s21; MRG32k3a_s21 = MRG32k3a_s22; MRG32k3a_s22 = p2;
    /* Combination */
    return ((p1 <= p2) ? (p1 - p2 + m1) : (p1 - p2)) * norm;
}

static uint32_t MRG32k3a_s10i, MRG32k3a_s11i, MRG32k3a_s12i;
static uint32_t MRG32k3a_s20i, MRG32k3a_s21i, MRG32k3a_s22i;

#if BUILTIN_64BIT
double MRG32k3a_i (void)
{
    const double norm = 2.328306549295728e-10;
    const uint32_t m1 = 4294967087u;
    const uint32_t m2 = 4294944443u;
    const uint32_t a12 = 1403580u;
    const uint32_t a13n = 810728u;
    const uint32_t a21 = 527612u;
    const uint32_t a23n = 1370589u;
    uint64_t prod;
    uint32_t p1, p2;

    /* Component 1 */
    prod = ((uint64_t)a12) * MRG32k3a_s11i - ((uint64_t)a13n) * MRG32k3a_s10i;
    prod = ((uint64_t)a13n) * m1 + prod; // ensure it's positive
    p1 = (uint32_t)(prod % m1);
    MRG32k3a_s10i=MRG32k3a_s11i; MRG32k3a_s11i=MRG32k3a_s12i; MRG32k3a_s12i=p1;
    /* Component 2 */
    prod = ((uint64_t)a21) * MRG32k3a_s22i - ((uint64_t)a23n) * MRG32k3a_s20i;
    prod = ((uint64_t)a23n) * m2 + prod; // ensure it's positive
    p2 = (uint32_t)(prod % m2);
    MRG32k3a_s20i=MRG32k3a_s21i; MRG32k3a_s21i=MRG32k3a_s22i; MRG32k3a_s22i=p2;
    /* Combination */
    return ((p1 <= p2) ? (p1 - p2 + m1) : (p1 - p2)) * norm;
}
#elif GENERIC_MOD
uint64_t umul64hi (uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    uint32_t alo = (uint32_t)a;
    uint32_t ahi = (uint32_t)(a >> 32);
    uint32_t blo = (uint32_t)b;
    uint32_t bhi = (uint32_t)(b >> 32);
    uint64_t p0 = (uint64_t)alo * blo;
    uint64_t p1 = (uint64_t)alo * bhi;
    uint64_t p2 = (uint64_t)ahi * blo;
    uint64_t p3 = (uint64_t)ahi * bhi;
    return (p1 >> 32) + (((p0 >> 32) + (uint64_t)(uint32_t)p1 + p2) >> 32) + p3;
}

double MRG32k3a_i (void)
{
    const double norm = 2.328306549295728e-10;
    const uint32_t m1 = 4294967087u;
    const uint32_t m2 = 4294944443u;
    const uint32_t a12 = 1403580u;
    const uint32_t a13n = 810728u;
    const uint32_t a21 = 527612u;
    const uint32_t a23n = 1370589u;
    const uint32_t neg_m1 = 0 - m1; // 209
    const uint32_t neg_m2 = 0 - m2; // 22853
    const uint64_t magic_mul_m1 = 0x8000006880005551ull;
    const uint64_t magic_mul_m2 = 0x4000165147c845ddull;
    const uint32_t shft_m1 = 31;
    const uint32_t shft_m2 = 30;
    uint64_t prod;
    uint32_t p1, p2;

    /* Component 1 */
    prod = ((uint64_t)a12) * MRG32k3a_s11i - ((uint64_t)a13n) * MRG32k3a_s10i;
    prod = ((uint64_t)a13n) * m1 + prod; // ensure it's positive
    p1 = (uint32_t)((umul64hi (prod, magic_mul_m1) >> shft_m1) * neg_m1 + prod);
    MRG32k3a_s10i=MRG32k3a_s11i; MRG32k3a_s11i=MRG32k3a_s12i; MRG32k3a_s12i=p1;
    /* Component 2 */
    prod = ((uint64_t)a21) * MRG32k3a_s22i - ((uint64_t)a23n) * MRG32k3a_s20i;
    prod = ((uint64_t)a23n) * m2 + prod; // ensure it's positive
    p2 = (uint32_t)((umul64hi (prod, magic_mul_m2) >> shft_m2) * neg_m2 + prod);
    MRG32k3a_s20i=MRG32k3a_s21i; MRG32k3a_s21i=MRG32k3a_s22i; MRG32k3a_s22i=p2;
    /* Combination */
    return ((p1 <= p2) ? (p1 - p2 + m1) : (p1 - p2)) * norm;
}
#else // !BUILTIN_64BIT && !GENERIC_MOD --> special fast modulo computation
double MRG32k3a_i (void)
{
    const double norm = 2.328306549295728e-10;
    const uint32_t m1 = 4294967087u;
    const uint32_t m2 = 4294944443u;
    const uint32_t a12 = 1403580u;
    const uint32_t a13n = 810728u;
    const uint32_t a21 = 527612u;
    const uint32_t a23n = 1370589u;
    const uint32_t neg_m1 = 0 - m1; // 209
    const uint32_t neg_m2 = 0 - m2; // 22853
    uint64_t prod;
    uint32_t p1, p2, prod_lo, prod_hi, adj;

    /* Component 1 */
    prod = ((uint64_t)a12) * MRG32k3a_s11i - ((uint64_t)a13n) * MRG32k3a_s10i;
    prod = ((uint64_t)a13n) * m1 + prod; // ensure its positive
    // ! special modulo computation: prod must be < 2**56 !
    prod_lo = (uint32_t)prod;
    prod_hi = (uint32_t)(prod >> 32);
    p1 = prod_hi * neg_m1 + prod_lo;
    if ((p1 >= m1) || (p1 < prod_lo)) p1 += neg_m1;
    MRG32k3a_s10i=MRG32k3a_s11i; MRG32k3a_s11i=MRG32k3a_s12i; MRG32k3a_s12i=p1;
    /* Component 2 */
    prod = ((uint64_t)a21) * MRG32k3a_s22i - ((uint64_t)a23n) * MRG32k3a_s20i;
    adj = MRG32k3a_s20i / 3133 - (MRG32k3a_s22i >> 13) + 1;
    prod = ((int64_t)(int32_t)adj) * (int64_t)m2 + prod; // ensure it's positive
    // ! special modulo computation: prod must be < 2**49 !
    prod_lo = (uint32_t)prod;
    prod_hi = (uint32_t)(prod >> 32);
    p2 = prod_hi * neg_m2 + prod_lo;
    if ((p2 >= m2) || (p2 < prod_lo)) p2 += neg_m2;
    MRG32k3a_s20i=MRG32k3a_s21i; MRG32k3a_s21i=MRG32k3a_s22i; MRG32k3a_s22i=p2;
    /* Combination */
    return ((p1 <= p2) ? (p1 - p2 + m1) : (p1 - p2)) * norm;
}
#endif // BUILTIN_64BIT

/*
  http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html
  By Bob Jenkins, 1996.  bob_jenkins@burtleburtle.net.  You may use this
  code any way you wish, private, educational, or commercial.  It's free.
*/
#define mix(a,b,c) \
    (a -= b, a -= c, a ^= (c>>13), \
     b -= c, b -= a, b ^= (a<<8),  \
     c -= a, c -= b, c ^= (b>>13), \
     a -= b, a -= c, a ^= (c>>12), \
     b -= c, b -= a, b ^= (a<<16), \
     c -= a, c -= b, c ^= (b>>5),  \
     a -= b, a -= c, a ^= (c>>3),  \
     b -= c, b -= a, b ^= (a<<10), \
     c -= a, c -= b, c ^= (b>>15))

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t m1 = 4294967087u;
    uint32_t m2 = 4294944443u;
    uint32_t a, b, c;
    a = 3141592654u;
    b = 2718281828u;
    c = 10; MRG32k3a_s10 = MRG32k3a_s10i = (1u << 10) | (mix (a, b, c) % m1);
    c = 11; MRG32k3a_s11 = MRG32k3a_s11i = (1u << 11) | (mix (a, b, c) % m1);
    c = 12; MRG32k3a_s12 = MRG32k3a_s12i = (1u << 12) | (mix (a, b, c) % m1);
    c = 20; MRG32k3a_s20 = MRG32k3a_s20i = (1u << 20) | (mix (a, b, c) % m2);
    c = 21; MRG32k3a_s21 = MRG32k3a_s21i = (1u << 21) | (mix (a, b, c) % m2);
    c = 22; MRG32k3a_s22 = MRG32k3a_s22i = (1u << 22) | (mix (a, b, c) % m2);
    
    double res, ref;
    uint64_t count = 0;
    do {
        res = MRG32k3a_i();
        ref = MRG32k3a();
        if (res != ref) {
            printf("\ncount=%llu  ref=%23.16e  res=%23.16e\n", count, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        count++;
        if ((count & 0xfffffff) == 0) printf ("\rcount = %llu ", count);
    } while (ref != 0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why cast twice? (int64_t)(int32_t)adj

Comment: Ah yes. it sign extends only a signed integer type. When you say 'must be positive', do you mean strictly greater than 0? That's an odd modulus function.

Comment: @njuffa Minor: comment `prod = ((uint64_t)a13n) * m1 + prod; // ensure it's positive` deserves review.  Even without this line of code, the _unsigned_ object `prod` is positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested or benchmarked this, but if I've understood what you're doing correctly, I think another option is to add a fixed multiple of m2 and have two rounds of reduction.

```
prod = ((uint64_t)a21) * MRG32k3a_s22i + ((uint64_t)m2 << 22) - ((uint64_t)a23n) * MRG32k3a_s20i; // 55 bits
```

Then you can omit the following two lines.

```
adj = MRG32k3a_s20i / 3133 - (MRG32k3a_s22i >> 13) + 1;
prod = ((int64_t)(int32_t)adj) * (int64_t)m2 + prod; // ensure it's positive
```

and then do

```
prod_lo = (uint32_t)prod; 
prod_hi = (uint32_t)(prod >> 32); // 23 bits
prod = (uint64_t)prod_hi * neg_m2 + prod_lo; // 39 bits
prod_lo = (uint32_t)prod; 
prod_hi = (uint32_t)(prod >> 32); 
p2 = prod_hi * neg_m2 + prod_lo; 
if ((p2 >= m2) || (p2 < prod_lo)) p2 += neg_m2;
```

You also might want to change the Component 1 calculation to something like

```
/* Component 1 */
prod = ((uint64_t)a12) * MRG32k3a_s11i + ((uint64_t)a13n) * (m1 - MRG32k3a_s10i); // 54 bits
```

instead of the 2 steps

```
/* Component 1 */
prod = ((uint64_t)a12) * MRG32k3a_s11i - ((uint64_t)a13n) * MRG32k3a_s10i;
prod = ((uint64_t)a13n) * m1 + prod; // ensure its positive
```

so as to not rely on the compiler being clever enough to realise it only needs two multiplications. I think this is valid as 0 <= MRG32k3a_s1xi < m1 right?

Comment: No mismatches with my test scaffold so far, +1. Performance-wise this appears to involve a similar number of operations in general and multiplies in particular judging by the source code, so it will likely be a wash but I will take a closer look; it could easily differ by platform: GPUs are good at IMADs, and so is ARM.

Comment: Excellent work! From what I can tell from a quick look, your multi-stage reduction improves performance by around 5%. That is more than I anticipated; I will have to look at the details of the generated code. Please note that I usually keep my questions open for five days to a week to maximize the number and quality of answers.

Comment: Yes, I should've noticed they were both constants. Why do you say it isn't production quality code?

Comment: For reasons I do not fully understand right now, your suggestion regarding folding the adjustment into the multiplication saves *six* instructions when I compile with Clang for RISC-V, from 93 instructions down to 87. I don't actually have RISC-V hardware available to me to measure performance, but this should result in a measurable improvement in performance. It may have something to do with the inefficiency of loading large constants in most 32-bit RISC architectures, which are typically loaded as multiple immediate constants that are ORed together. So thank you for that suggestion as well!

Comment: One letter variable names is disgraceful! I use temp1, var2 etc. :D